# Code is not validating: TypeError cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Tags: python, string

While loops are new to me and I'm having trouble getting my code to validate.

---

**Description**

> In this exercise your function will receive two parameters: a
>   string(long_word) and a character(char). Use a while loop to go
>   through all the letters in the string and build a new string made up
>   from those letters until you find the char. You may assume that each
>   string will contain the passed in character(char).

**This is my code.**

```
def letters_up_to_char(long_word, char):
    new = ""
    i = 0
    while i != char:
        for letter in long_word:
            new += letter
        i += 1
    return new
```

**Example output**

```
letters_up_to_char('coderoxthesox', 'x') -> 'codero'
letters_up_to_char('abcdefghijklmnop', 'f') -> 'abcde'
```

When I go to run my code I get:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Comment: Just a remark that you can relay to the person that gave the assignment to you: This is a horrible eay of teaching Python. The algoritm described violate every best practice pattern for Python and is highly inefficient. Do not teach this to students! (If the person is interested I can explain in details.)

Answer (score 1):

> To get rid of `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'xyz' objects`, just
>   cast the object being concatenated to a string. If your code was
>   `string + num` or `string += num` just cast `num` to string like so:
>   `str(num)`

BUT, your code won't return the desired output. See why below:

If I'm not mistaken, the code *shouldn't* compile because when `new` is defined, you don't close the **double quotes**. Or if you are using **single quotes**, change your code and your question to reflect your change.

When I ran your code and executed it, it went in an infinite loop, the beginner's worst enemy! In your code, the

```
for letter in long_word:
    new += letter
```

Is the same as saying `new += long_word`, because you are just adding the individual characters instead of the whole string at one go.

Your code can then be rewritten as follows:

```
def letters_up_to_char(long_word, char):
    new = ""
    i = 0
    while i != char:
        new += long_word
        i += 1
    return new
```

Now it is clear what your code is doing. It's just adding the whole word to `new` each time the while loop is executed. And the while loop is executed till `i != char`. Since `i` is an `int` and `char` is a `str`, `i != char` is always true. Infinite loop in the making!

Your function should look like this:

```
def letters_up_to_char(long_word, char):
    new = ""
    i = 0
    while i < len(long_word) and long_word[i] != char:
        new += long_word[i]
        i += 1
    return new
```

Explanation:
Go through each character in `long_word` from the start (this can be more easily accomplished using a `for...in` loop, but I'm using a while loop as per your request) and till the current character != `char`, add that character to `new`.
This code returns the desired output for both your test cases.

Answer (score 1):

Considering

> You may assume that each string will contain the passed in
>   character(char).

not including the char:

```
def letters_up_to_char(long_word, char):
        i=0
        while long_word[i] != char:
            i+=1
        return long_word[:i]
```

including the char:

```
def letters_up_to_char(long_word, char):
        i=0
        while long_word[i] != char:
            i+=1
        return long_word[:i+1]
```

Though a more pythonic way is, i.e.:

```
def letters_up_to_char(long_word, char):
    return long_word.partition(char)[0]
```

Suggest you to use http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html as a reference, when completing your assignments.

Answer (score 0):

The "i" is `int` type which cannot be compared with a `str` type "char".

```
while i < len(long_word) and long_word[i] != char
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways similar to this to write this code. In your example, the `while i != char` line is going to result in a very long loop because it will loop until `i == int(char)`, or possibly infinitely. I would write it with either a `for` **or** a `while`, as below:

```
def letters_while(long_word, char):
    new = ""
    i = 0
    # A second condition is needed to prevent an infinite loop
    # in the case that char is not in long_word
    while long_word[i] != char and i < len(long_word):
        new += letter
        i += 1
    return new

def letters_for(long_word, char):
   new = ""
   for letter in long_word:
        if letter != char:
            new += letter
   return new
```

As a note, these are easy to understand examples, and a better way to do this would be

```
long_word.split(char)[0]
```